# Making Java RMI to run on netbeans 7

Tags: java, rmi, netbeans-7

I have written RMI java code and started the RMI server manually, but when i run the program it brings an error of class not found, what am i missing:
Error:  RemoteException occurred in server thread; nested exception is: 
    java.rmi.UnmarshalException: error unmarshalling arguments; nested exception is: 
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: rmi3.Hello 
* the class is available

Comment: Is the `Object` you are sending over RMI available in the classpath of your project?

Comment: I have done this in my windows environment via command promp but still it has issues: C:\Users\123\Documents\NetBeansProjects\rmi3\src\rmi3\Hello.java

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the stack trace you will find out whether the exception is being thrown:

1. On export, which means the class isn't available on the server JVM's CLASSPATH
2. When binding, which means it isn't available on the RMI Registry's CLASSPATH.
3. When looking up, which means it isn't available on the client's CLASSPATH.